# How to express a lone "\" in a file path in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2003

I'm using a VBA script to save a file titled *"month-day-hour-minute"* inside of a folder titled *"month-year"*

Anyways, excel doesn't like my code,

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\" & Environ$("UserName") & _ 
"\Documents\Workout Logs\" & _
Format$(Date, "mmmm-yyyy") & _ 
"\" & _ 
Format$(Date, "mmmm-dd") & Format$(Time, "hh-mm") & ".xls"
```

Specifically this part

```
"\" & _
```

How do I express the \ break in the pathing in a way that it likes so it sees

```
Format$(Date, "mmmm-yyyy") & _
```

as the folder in which the file that will be saved as

```
Format$(Date, "mmmm-dd") & Format$(Time, "hh-mm") & ".xls"
```

should be placed in?

Comment: well, VBA/VBS doesn't require escape sequences except for doublequotes, so while I would normally suggest that you double your backslashes, it probably won't help. have you tried splitting it into multiple lines? VB editors can often be confused by `& _` and if you are having trouble concatenating multiple expressions, and those expressions are the result of a function call, there can be casting issues that are hard to anticipate. try generating the path tokens seperately in their own vars, and finally concat them together.

Comment: After a short break cursing MS, my first attempt would be to include the backslash in the date format, but I haven't checked the manual. It's just that sometimes these formatting functions are more flexible than one tends to think. -- I wouldn't exclude that it might need to be escaped there, although the other comment suggest that this is not the case.

Comment: You could use CHR$(x) where x is the asci code of \

Answer (score 0):

This runs fine on my computer (Windows Excel 2013)

```
Sub test()
a = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("UserName") & _
"\Documents\Workout Logs\" & _
Format$(Date, "mmmm-yyyy") & _
"\" & _
Format$(Date, "mmmm-dd") & Format$(Time, "hh-mm") & ".xls"

MsgBox (a)

End Sub
```

Msgbox results `C:\Users\username\Documents\Workout Logs\May-2016\May-1910-13.xls`

Its the same thing it just saves the string to a variable instead of saving the document.

Comment: So it does, I guess I was making an assumption that it was the "\". I still get an error message but apparently it's unrelated that.